# Is it possible to prevent transition from router.setRouteLeaveHook within route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have following routes:

```
/user/:id(/contacts)
/dashboard
```

and User component has following `setRouteLeaveHook` (`return false` means to prevent the transition):

```
componentWillMount() {
  const currentRoute = _.last(this.props.router.routes);
  this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(currentRoute, (nextLoc) => {
    return false;
  });
}
```

this work well when I am at e.g. `/user/2` and navigate to `dashboard`.

But when I am at `/user/2` and navigate to `/user/3`, or to `user/3/contact`, the callback in `setRouteLeaveHook` is called, but the `return false` has no effect, and the transition occurs.

Technically, in the second scenario I don't leave the route `/user/:id(/contacts)`, so the behaviour makes sense given the name `setRouteLeaveHook`, but -- I would expect the callback inside `setRouteLeaveHook` wont be called at all for such in-route transition.

I am using react-router 3.2.0.